# My Accumulator is not working in VB (Visual Studio 2010)

Tags: vb.net

My accumulator (decTotalCredits) is not working properly and is resetting to zero with each entry.  I am needing the accumulator to add in each user input until it hits 125. As it normally is, I'm sure it's something small.  Thanks in advance for all your help!

```
    ' Declaring variable for Credit Entered by User
    Dim decCredit As Decimal = CDec(txtCredit.Text)
    ' Declaring the accumulator
    Dim decTotalCredits As Decimal

    If IsNumeric(txtCredit.Text) Then
        decCredit = Convert.ToDecimal(txtCredit.Text)
        Select Case decCredit
            Case Is = 5
            Case Is = 10
            Case Is = 25
            Case Is = 100
            Case Else
                MsgBox("Please enter a valid coin amount", , "Invalid Amount Entered")
        End Select

        If decTotalCredits < 125 Then

            decTotalCredits += decCredit
            lblTotal.Text = CStr(decTotalCredits)
            lblTotal.Visible = True

            txtCredit.Clear()
            txtCredit.Focus()

        Else

            ' Once the credits are reached the prompt to make selection is visible. 
            lblMakeSelection.Visible = True

            ' Once the credits are reached, the buttons for selection become enabled.
            btnDietPepsi.Enabled = True
            btnPepsi.Enabled = True
            btnSierraMist.Enabled = True
            btnLemonade.Enabled = True
            btnDrPepper.Enabled = True
            btnWater.Enabled = True
        End If
    Else
        MsgBox("Please enter a valid Coin amount", , "Input Error")


    End If
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's being redeclared..

- If this is in a loop you need to declare DecTotalCredits outside of your loop.
- If this is in an event handler you need to declare DecTotalCredits At the top of your code (right below the declaration of the class) That way it doesn't get redeclared everytime the handler runs

Comment: Thank you so much!  I moved it up to the class level and it works wonderfully!  I'm putting this in my notes as well!