# My accumulator and calculations are not working in VB 2010

Tags: vb.net

OK, so my accumulator is now adding and showing properly in the form as a total.  However, something is wrong in my if...  then statement and it's not throwing it to the 2nd level after reaching the 125.  I can hit 125 and I need to make an entry to get my buttons to be enabled.  Any help is appreciated!

**Edit to show updated with the Do While Loop.  Now causing issues with my input error msgbox...  **

```
do while decTotalCredits < 125 
        If IsNumeric(txtCredit.Text) Then
            ' This statement will convert the string entered to decimal and establish the 
            ' input as the decCredit Variable
            decCredit = Convert.ToDecimal(txtCredit.Text)
            ' This Case Statement is to verify that the correct denominations of coins are 
            ' being entered in the machine. 
            Select Case decCredit
                Case 5, 10, 25, 100
                    ' This line adds the newly entered credit to the 
                    ' exsisting total
                    decTotalCredits += decCredit
                    lblTotal.Text = Convert.ToString(decTotalCredits)
                    lblTotal.Visible = True
                    ' reset the text input box for the credit amount
                    txtCredit.Clear()
                    txtCredit.Focus()
                Case Else
                    ' This message will appear if a Credit is entered that does not
                    ' conform to normal coins
                    MsgBox("Please enter a valid coin amount", , "Invalid Amount Entered")
            End Select
        Else
            ' This message will occur when a user inputs a non-numeric entry
            MsgBox("Please enter a valid Coin amount", , "Input Error")
        End If
    Loop

    ' Loop should complete when credits hit 125 and activate this code
    ' Once the credits are reached the prompt to make selection is visible. 
    lblMakeSelection.Visible = True
    ' Once the credits are reached, the buttons for selection become enabled.
    btnDietPepsi.Enabled = True
    btnPepsi.Enabled = True
    btnSierraMist.Enabled = True
    btnLemonade.Enabled = True
    btnDrPepper.Enabled = True
    btnWater.Enabled = True

End Sub
```

Comment: You're checking the total credits before you add the current credits.

Comment: Thank you...  I have changed the original IF statement to a Do While Loop...  giving me errors with my msgbox's now...  they pop up and do not allow entry of new data...  It is the "INPUT ERROR" that is giving me the trouble

Comment: Why is it in a loop? That's guaranteed not to work now...

Comment: possible duplicate of [My Accumulator is not working in VB (Visual Studio 2010)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10110597/my-accumulator-is-not-working-in-vb-visual-studio-2010)

Comment: It is not a duplicate, as now my accumulator is calculating correctly.  however, it is not kicking to the 2nd level of the if statement until I enter another entry after hitting 125...  so I'm not sure...  I'm working on it ... thanks for your help.  This is the first VB class I've taken so I'm a total noob...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the code you have given us, it will enter the loop, add to the total, wipe the txtCredit textbox, start the loop again and then show error message box because txtCredit is no longer a numeric.

Assuming that logic is in a button click or TextBox Validate routine, suggest you remove the loop and add a "If decTotalCredit >= 125 Then " statement before the enabling of buttons.

Comment: I did go back to the if... then statements, one for < 125 and one for >= 125.  This fixed my issue and now my program is working!  THANKS!